# Change the width of a Div by selecting the Div attribute

Tags: javascript

I have the following Div, which have an attribute named `data-automation-id`:-

[image]

now i want using javascript to set the width of this Div to be 50% then back to 75% instead of 100%? but i am not sure how i can select a Div using an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
document.querySelector("div[data-automation-id='CanvasLayout']").style.width="50%";
```

Or with Jquery:

```
$("div[data-automation-id='CanvasLayout']").css("width","50%");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors